# Detecting near duplicates above a threshold

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to query a table for records I suspect may be nearly duplicates.

I've racked my brains but can't think where to begin with this one, so I've simplified the problem as much as possible, and came to ask here!

Here's my simplified table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
  `id1` int auto_increment primary key, 
  `amount` decimal(6,2),
  `date` datetime
);
```

Here's some test values:

```
INSERT INTO sales
(`amount`, `date`)
VALUES
(10, '2013-05-15T11:11:00'),
(11, '2013-05-15T11:11:11'),
(20, '2013-05-15T11:22:00'),
(3,  '2013-05-15T12:12:00'),
(4,  '2013-05-15T12:12:12'),
(45, '2013-05-15T12:22:00'),
(4,  '2013-05-15T12:24:00'),
(8,  '2013-05-15T13:00:00'),
(9,  '2013-05-15T13:01:00'),
(10, '2013-05-15T14:00:00');
```

**The problem**

I want to return sales above amount Y,  that have neighbour sales above Y that recorded within X minutes of each other.

ie, from this data:

```
amt, date
(10, '2013-05-15T11:11:00'),
(11, '2013-05-15T11:11:11'),
(20, '2013-05-15T11:22:00'),
(3,  '2013-05-15T12:12:00'),
(4,  '2013-05-15T12:12:12'),
(45, '2013-05-15T12:22:00'),
(4,  '2013-05-15T12:24:00'),
(8,  '2013-05-15T13:00:00'),
(9,  '2013-05-15T13:01:00'),
(10, '2013-05-15T14:00:00');
```

where `@yVal = 5` and `@xMins = 10`

expected result would be:

```
(10, '2013-05-15T11:11:00'),
(11, '2013-05-15T11:11:11'),
(20, '2013-05-15T11:22:00'),
(8,  '2013-05-15T13:00:00'),
(9,  '2013-05-15T13:01:00'),
```

I've put the above into a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf8fe

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somthing like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.* FROM sales s1
    LEFT JOIN sales s2 
    ON (s1.id1 != s2.id1 
            AND s1.amount >= s2.amount - @xVal AND s1.amount <= s2.amount + @xVal
            AND s1.date >= DATE_SUB(s2.date, INTERVAL @xMins minute) AND s1.date <= DATE_ADD(s2.date, INTERVAL @xMins minute)
    )
    WHERE
    s2.id1 is not null
```

#### Extends

Fix some errors

Result for your data looks like:

```
+-----+--------+---------------------+
| id1 | amount | date                |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
|   1 |  10.00 | 2013-05-15 11:11:00 | 
|   2 |  11.00 | 2013-05-15 11:11:11 |
|   4 |   3.00 | 2013-05-15 12:12:00 |
|   5 |   4.00 | 2013-05-15 12:12:12 |
|   8 |   8.00 | 2013-05-15 13:00:00 |
|   9 |   9.00 | 2013-05-15 13:01:00 |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
```

#### Extends 2

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s1.* FROM sales s1
    LEFT JOIN sales s2
    ON (s1.id1 != s2.id1
        AND s2.amount >= @xVal
        AND s1.date >= DATE_SUB(s2.date, INTERVAL @xMins minute) AND s1.date <= DATE_ADD(s2.date, INTERVAL @xMins minute)
    )
    WHERE
    s2.id1 is not null 
    AND s1.amount >= @xVal
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much more progress than I have so far, but it's not giving the right result.  The 11:22:00 should be returned as is within 10 mins of 11:11:11, which is itself already selected as part of a duplicate with 11:11:00.  The amounts 4 and 3 are being returned, despite being less than xVal (which is 5).

Comment: I has not right undestend condtion aboud xVal - look extends2. About 11:22:00 and 11:11:11, they have difference in 00:10:49, this is more than 10 minutes. If you need include 00:10:xx diference, add 1 to @xMins in query

Comment: You are right, oops!  Extends2 returns exactly the right answer and I cannot find any bugs.  Thank you very much.